# How to get data from label box?

Tags: python

I have a link that leads to an image. How can I get it or download it with python?
This is the link of the image:
https://storage.labelbox.com/ckc5wddcn1f6x0766ewd1yuc1%2Fa58f8ca1-3265-ad38-6c3d-c71e8e6a88a6-image852.jpg?Expires=1597225683779&KeyName=labelbox-assets-key-1&Signature=PpAGopCySjZQz4r49sLPaa72CLs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `requests` module to download the image

```
import requests

res = requests.get("https://storage.labelbox.com/ckc5wddcn1f6x0766ewd1yuc1%2Fa58f8ca1-3265-ad38-6c3d-c71e8e6a88a6-image852.jpg?Expires=1597225683779&KeyName=labelbox-assets-key-1&Signature=PpAGopCySjZQz4r49sLPaa72CLs")

with open("a.jpg", "wb") as f:
    f.write(res.content)
```

Comment: Thank for your help. I did it